# How to include a conditional OR statement in the SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, logical-operators

In my SQL statement if the value of Type is equal to 'T' then I want to add a conditional OR clause as shown below. Otherwise, there will be no  OR clause

```
if type not equal to 'T':
    select customerid, type from customer
    where cityid = '20' 

if type is equal to 'T'
    select customerid, type from customer
    where cityid = '20' OR cityid = '5'
```

Comment: Aside: Is `cityid` really a string? Your code compares it to string (`'20'`), rather than `int` (`20`), values.

Comment: Yes, cityid is a string.

Comment: Is `type` a column in the table or a variable (`@type`) in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly its assuming that where you have written `type` you mean `@type`.

You can always combine this type of logic using `OR` e.g.

```
select customerid, @type
from customer
where
-- Condition from first branch
(@type != 'T' and cityid = '20')
-- Condition from second branch
or (@type = 'T' and (cityid = '5' or cityid = '20'));
```

Being extra careful with your brackets to ensure you get the required logic.

Note: [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) i.e. `AND` is evaluated before `OR` hence the brackets.

This can be simplified to:

```
select customerid, @type
from customer
where cityid = '20'
or (
    cityid = '5' and @type = 'T'
);
```

However `OR` has a nasty habit of causing performance issues, should this happen you can use `union all` instead e.g.

```
select customerid, @type
from customer
where @type != 'T' and cityid = '20'

union all

select customerid, @type
from customer
where @type = 'T' and (cityid = '5' or cityid = '20');
```

Others have suggested using a `case` in the where clause, but with that you run the risk of making it non-sargable i.e. unable to use indexes, and to my mind its harder to read. Its best IMO to learn to use complex logic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are refactoring a stored procedure.

Assuming `type` is a stored procedure variable or parameter rather than a column in the `customer` table, I would put it like this:

```
select c.customerid,
       c.type
from customer c
where 1 = case coalesce( @type, '' )
            when 'T' then case when c.cityid in ('20', '5') then 1 else 0 end
            else          case when c.cityid in ('20'     ) then 1 else 0 end
          end
```

The test against `@type` is wrapped in a `coalesce()` function because `null` fails any test save an explicit test for nullity.

I'm using a `case` *expression* here as well, because it make things more tabular, and when you need to add a new case for when `@type` is 'Z'... it's just an additional `when` clause. And it avoid possible confusion surrounding operator precedence between `and` and `or`.

Comment: When was a `case` _statement_ added to TSQL? I'm only familiar with the [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_ that your code uses.

Comment: Nicholas, it's not a stored proc I am trying to refactor. We have several crazy legacy SQL expressions I have to work with.

Comment: Fixed it for ya. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement. Think of each "when" as your if statement; after that, you can add the where statement logic.

```sql
SELECT
    customerid,
    type
FROM customer
WHERE 
    1 = CASE
            WHEN type <> 'T' AND cityid = '20' THEN 1 -- not equal to 'T'
            WHEN type = 'T' AND (cityid = '20' OR cityid = '5') THEN 1 -- type is equal to 'T'
            ELSE 0 
        END
```

Comment: Whats the advantage of using a case **expression** over the actual logic? It adds a layer of complexity, and potentially hinders performance.

Comment: @DaleK,

In the case that the query was more complex and the only difference was the If statement section, we will be copying the code twice. Thus, by making it a where statement we can make the code more readable.

It is true that it might hinder performance; if the case statement expression is simple enough, the performance impact might be neglectable.

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean logic:

```
select customerid, type from customer
where cityid = '20' or
      (cityid = '5' and type = 'T')
```

I would suggest that you avoid `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  They impede optimization.